# Authentification using Nextjs, next-auth and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt

After logging a user on the frontend with next-auth and nextjs, I want to be able to send the cookie generated by next-auth to the backend nodejs in order to validate before the user can do actions like adding posts.
Basically I want to check if user is authenticated on the backend using the cookie session.

I tried the send the cookie on the request but the backend doesn’t capture it since frontend and backend are on different domains.
Otherwise what’s the best solution to authenticate users on next js and mode js app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to provide a more specific question as this is rather vague, but generally I'd recommend using a package like cors server side, so your BE app will accept requests from the FE. https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/

For example -

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
}));
```

If you're experiencing a different error, please provide code samples and more details.